# Encryption on iOS5 vs iOS4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption, ios5

The following code results in `status = 0` on iOS4.3 SDK on iOS4.3:

```
size_t mySize, cypherSize;
mySize = (secKeyGetBlockSize() - 11);
// Code that reads in mySize bytes into buffer and
// sets cipherSize to secKeyGetBlockSize().
// [...]
status = SecKeyEncrypt(myPublicKey,
                       kSecPaddingPKCS1,
                       myBuffer,
                       mySize,
                       myBuffer,
                       &cipherSize);
```

It turns out that `setKeyGetBlockSize()` is `256` and thus `mySize = 245`. `cypherSize` is always `256` after returning from `SecKeyEncrypt`.

On iOS5 SDK running on iOS5, the same above code results in `status = -50`! After some experiments I found that `mySize = 244` (one lower than previously!) works again. I checked the documentation of `SecKeyEncrypt` on iOS5.0 and it has not changed - thus, the size should not have changed, either.

What is the reason for this difference?

Comment: Why are you passing exactly `SecKeyGetBlockSize()-11` as `mySize`? That's the *maximum* size you can pass, but you're *supposed* to pass the number of bytes in `myBuffer`.

Comment: In the code that sets up the buffer I set `mySize` to the value read from a file. The file typically is larger than 256 bytes, so most of the time `mySize` will indeed be at the maximum value. I have clarified the code block in the question.

Comment: This happened to me as well, and solution is the same (doing block size -12 instead of -11) but it doesn't make any sense at all. did you find more info about this?

Comment: No, I didn't. I should submit a bug report to Apple, but they always ask for a sample project that demonstrates the behavior ... and for that I need a device with iOS 4.x (as the simulator does not support the API). Figuring out how to install an older iOS version on a current device is definitely too much hassle for me right now!

Comment: You found any info on this yet? Anything?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not made progress on this. I have not revisited this issue on iOS 6.x, so it may even be resolved on newer machines. Otherwise, the work-around continues to consist of setting the block size-12 (instead of -11) when feeding the data into the `SecKeyEncrypt ` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is `cipherSize`. You're leaving that variable uninitialized, but on input to `SecKeyEncrypt()` it's supposed to contain the size of your `myBuffer` buffer (on output it contains the number of bytes actually written to that buffer).

Comment: Actually, it was not uninitialized. I have just skipped the initialization code of the buffer. On input, it is 256 bytes (the return value of `secKeyGetBlockSize()`) and on output it turns out to be 256 bytes as well. I have updated to question to reflect this situation.